# php5-fpm: unrecognized service.How to solve it?

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

When I run `homestead provision`,it returns `php5-fpm: unrecognised service`.

I've found an [answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/envoyer/php5-fpm-unrecognized-service) saying unchecking "*Restart FPM After Deployments*" in Server Options.But I can't find Server Options anywhere.And I'm not sure we got the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [How to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello. I've got same problem.  Run `vagrant box list` and check how many homestead boxes you have. My problem was with new box which contain php7-fpm but in vendor homestead trying to start php5-fmp so I did composer update and this fixed the issue .

Comment: Thank you @Victor!But I can't figure out what's wrong with my problem.Is it the title?Sorry to bother...

Comment: @Maya, no, it's not the title. It should you should rephrase the question so it looks more like a question, just so it looks better :D

Comment: Thank you @dychenko ! I've got two boxes.laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0) and laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0.4.1).I've run `composer update` but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Victor I've change it. :)

Comment: so you can remove one newest box or remove `"laravel/homestead"` from dependencies (composer.json) and add it again using `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`

Comment: I've remove the newest box.I'm using homestead2.0,but after running `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`,the require-dev is `"laravel/homestead": "^3.0"` So I change my homestead version to 3.0 too.But the new version don't provide command `homestead provision`,so I don't know whether the php-fpm is working...(BTW,I'm using PHP56)

Comment: If you removed newest box you can use old version of homestead dependency. And if you update dependency you should update box.

Comment: @dyachenko Thank you!You solved my problem!laravel/homestead version 0 actually is version 0.4.1 ,too.I download version 0.3.0 and using homestead2.0.And it worked!Why don't you put the comment into answer so I can vote you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got error `php5-fpm: unrecognised service` usually it's happens because you have several homestead boxes (for check it run `vagrant box list`) (newest boxes use php7-fpm inside).

There are two ways to solve this problem:

- Remove newest homestead box.

**OR**

- Update your `laravel/homestead` dependency in `composer.json`  and use new version of homestead.